# <tbody> tag is removed after @swimlane/ngx-charts & @swimlane/ngx-graph version upgrade in Angular 8

Tags: xpath, angular8, angular-upgrade

I am updating angular from version 7 to version 8. For that i have updated @swimlane/ngx-charts & @swimlane/ngx-graph to below version

**"@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^12.1.0",
"@swimlane/ngx-graph": "^6.1.0"**

After version upgrade, Browser is not adding  tag dynamically in DOM HTML.
What could be the reason for that and how can i resolve it?

Xpath Before Upgrade:
/html/body/app-as-main-app/div/app-as-home/div/div[1]/app-as-integration-parent/div/div[2]/app-as-integration-list/app-as-integration-group/div/div[2]/**table/tbody/tr**/td[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/app-as-oh-typeahead-scrollable/div/app-as-oh-typeahead/ng-select

After Upgrade:

/html/body/app-as-main-app/div/app-as-home/div/div[1]/app-as-integration-parent/div/div[2]/app-as-integration-list/app-as-integration-group/div/div[2]/**table/tr**/td[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/app-as-oh-typeahead-scrollable/div/app-as-oh-typeahead/ng-select

If i downgrade @swimlane/ngx-charts & @swimlane/ngx-graph version, it will work fine but it is not compatible with Angular Version 8.